# Delete user with redux-thunk in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want to delete a user from firebase. And my action is called from a button.
`

```
   export const deleteAccount = () =>{
   return async (dispatch, getState) =>{
const token =getState().auth.token;
let response;
try{
 response = await fetch('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:delete? 
key=[My_API_key]',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token:token
        })
      });
    } catch(err){
     throw new Error(err.message);
     }
     if(!response.ok){
  const errorResData  = await response.json();
  console.log(errorResData);
  const errorId = errorResData.error.message;
  let message = 'Something went Wrong!';
  if(errorId === 'INVALID_ID_TOKEN'){
    message = 'Please Login Again!!'
  } else if(errorId === "USER_NOT_FOUND"){
    message = 'User Not Found';
  }
  throw new Error(message);
  }
  // dispatch(authentication(resData.localId, resData.idToken, parseInt(resData.expiresIn)*1000 ));
  dispatch({type: DELETE});
       }
    };
   `
```

on consoling my errorResData I am getting response
 `Object { "error": Object { "code": 400, "errors": Array [ Object { "domain": "global", "message": "MISSING_ID_TOKEN", "reason": "invalid", }, ], "message": "MISSING_ID_TOKEN", }, }`

if I console my token I am getting that token.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you aren't using the Firebase SDK to do this, but you should be using v3 of the Identity Toolkit API.

```
await fetch(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/deleteAccount",
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      idToken: FRESH_USER_ID_TOKEN
    })
  }
);
```

Comment: while passing idToken in body, I must use idToken or refreshToken?